# How to get a name of older package?

Tags: rhel, package-management, rpm

I have a RHEL and on one of servers I have installed the same RPM package in two different versions.

```
[root ~]# rpm -qa | grep my-package-name
my-package-name-6.6.2-129.x86_64
my-package-name-7.0.2-1.x86_64
```

I wonder if it is possible to receive only the older package name?
Basically I want to accomplish something like this:

```
[root ~]# rpm -qa | grep my-package-name | get-the-oldest-package
```

How can I do it?

Comment: you're looking for the oldest (lowest-version-number) of one specific package, or of any/all? your rpm command says "Query All", followed by a grep for a specific package, so I wasn't sure

Comment: I want the oldest package of one specific package named "my-package-name".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how you managed to install two versions of the same package, but this should do the job:

```
rpm -q --queryformat "%{VERSION} %{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.%{ARCH}\n" my-package-name | \
  sort -V | \
  awk 'NR==1 { print $2 }'
```

The first line queries the RPM database for my-package-name, asking RPM to provide the results in a specific format -- the VERSION followed by the default "rpm -qa" fields. This is piped to `sort -V` to (attempt) to sort the version numbers, followed by a pipe to `awk` to print only the first line, stripping off the additional VERSION field, resulting in the `rpm -qa` default output.

This makes the hopefully-safe assumption that you're running this on a RHEL system that has a `-V` flag for sort.

Comment: Regarding the first statement, if none of the files in the package overlap with one another they'll never come up as a conflict, IIRC that's how the kernel package works.

Comment: RPM supports installing multiple versions of a package, as long as nothing explicitly prevents it (such as the packages containing a common file). This is done routinely to have multiple versions of a library, there's no need to encode the library version in the package name like in the deb format.

Answer (score 3):

I'm always paranoid about depending on programs interpreting version strings, so as an alternative to Jeff's solution you could also do this:

```
[root@jb87-workstation ~]# rpm -q kernel --queryformat "%{INSTALLTIME} %{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.%{ARCH}\n" | sort -n | head -1 | awk '{print $NF}'
kernel-4.8.13-300.fc25.x86_64
```

(substituting `kernel` for your package name)

That essentially prints the full package name by doing your same `rpm -qa` command and just using `--queryformat` to prefix each line with the Unix timestamp of when it was installed (which is in the `%{INSTALLTIME}` tag). It then uses `sort -n` to sort the output from oldest to newest and just takes the first line of output and prints the last column which will be the full package name.

Jeff's works just fine, though. It's probably more of a question of personal preference.

Comment: I think that you don't need `-a` if you're giving rpm the package you're after (here, kernel). Apparently harmless, but extraneous.

Comment: Fair enough, I removed it for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use yum downgrade package-name. Sometimes new packages got a bug. I did downgrade to old package.